# Import Error with PYODBC - ubuntu - python 3.6 - Anaconda 4.3.1

Tags: pyodbc

I have an error importing pyodbc. The error say: undefined symbol: PySlice_Unpack.

I have been googling around but I have not find any solution yet..

Any help?

Many thanks!

s

Comment: How did you install `pyodbc`? Does it come with Anaconda? Is it possible that it installed alongside the system Python instead of Anaconda's version?

Comment: I installed pyodbc with pip. It didn't come with Anaconda. In the end I went back to Python 3.5 with PYMSSQL instead of PYODBC and everything is working fine now. Thanks.